# eclipse appcompat->res->drawable-xxxhdpi error

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-appcompat

I just updated my eclipse to `SDK 21`. I know that eveytime I create project the eclipse will also create project named `appcompat_v7`. but the `appcompat_v7` is showing error at the `res/drawable-xxxhdpi` folder. and  it also make my project error, and showing this alert at console

```
[2014-12-05 11:03:25 - Tast] invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\FahmiSDK\workspace\appcompat_v7\res/drawable-ldrtl-xxxhdpi
[2014-12-05 11:03:25 - Tast] invalid resource directory name: C:\Users\FahmiSDK\workspace\appcompat_v7\res/drawable-xxxhdpi
```

Please, help me, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: again import appcompat_v7 use this:    go ur adt-bundle-windows  package and  adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130522\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

Comment: @Eddie I follow the instruction in your link. and it works . Thank you

Comment: This issue happens to me when I attempt to use Android-SDK for x86. If I use the 64-bit version and recreate the appcompat project the errors no longer appear.