# Eclipse res->drawable-xxxhdpi error resources issue

Tags: android, eclipse

[[image: enter image description here[1]]

I just updated my eclipse to SDK 23. I dont know why that eveytime I create project the eclipse will also create project named appcompat_v7. but the appcompat_v7 is showing error at the res/drawable-xxxhdpi folder. and it also make my project error. If I trying to import another project in elipse then also i get the error at res/drawable-xxxhdpi folder

Please, help me, how to resolve this problem?

Comment: see this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308667/eclipse-appcompat-res-drawable-xxxhdpi-error

Comment: check all image names inside drawable_xxxhdpi folder .Names should only contain small letters and only  _   symbol nothing else, no capital letter

Comment: yep...all image name are in small leters.....i added image have a look

Comment: Your question is like an exact duplicate of that other post... Word for word

Comment: sory for that i'm new to android and i'm nt geting answers of why eveytime I create project the eclipse will also create project named appcompat_v7....but still m facing this problem. what should i do